# Matlab fitcsvm gives me a zero training error and 40% in testing

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I know its over-fitting to the training data set, yet I dont know how to change the parameters to avoid this. 
I have tried changing the boxcontraint from 1e0, 1e1, 1e10 and got the same situation.

```
tTargets = ones(size(trainTargets,1),1);
tTargets(trainTargets(:,2)==1)=-1;

svmModel = fitcsvm(trainData, ...
    tTargets,...
    'KernelFunction','rbf',...
    'BoxConstraint',1e0);
[Group, score] = predict(svmModel, trainData);
tTargets = ones(size(trainTargets,1),1);
tTargets(trainTargets(:,2)==1)=-1;
svmTrainError = sum(tTargets ~= Group)/size(trainTargets,1);

[Group, score] = predict(svmModel, testData);
tTargets = ones(size(testTargets,1),1);
tTargets(testTargets(:,2)==1)=-1;
svmTestError = sum(tTargets ~= Group)/size(testTargets,1);
```

I hope someone can help with this
Thanks,

Comment: How do you select the train and test data? Have you tried random data selection?

Comment: Giving insight on your actual data can also help.

Comment: @NKN, yeah I have tried using different parts of the same data set as training and testing set.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks, I had found that the problem was the C or boxconstraint was to big and that I needed to try several so there was no overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was using a big C for the training. This made that the separation on the training data was really good but not for the testing. 
Changing the C for a smaller value (1e-2) made my code run faster and now I have comparable over all accuracy in the training and testing. 
Thank you!!!!